# Can a hidden input field be shown using pure CSS?

Tags: html, input-field

Can a `<input type="hidden">` field be shown using pure CSS?

I'd like to use an browser extension like Stylus to modify the CSS of a webpage. I tried adding a `display: block` style in the hope that the input field just has a global browser style that prevents it from being rendered, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hidden inputs are completely invisible in the rendered page, and there
> is no way to make [them] visible in the page's content.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden